# How do you avoid the promise constructor antipattern with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

How do you avoid the promise constructor antipattern when using multiple promises and `Promise.all`?

Say I have the following code:

```
getFoo = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var promises = [];
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => {
            getBar1().then(function(bar1) {
                processBar1(bar1); 
                resolve(bar1);
            });
        }));
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => {
            getBar2().then(function(bar2) {
                processBar2(bar2); 
                resolve(bar2);
            });
        }));
        Promise.all(promises).spread(function(bar1, bar2) {
            var result = processBothBars(bar1, bar2);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

It presents some of the fundamental issues of the antipattern, errors get swallowed up, and pyramids of doom.

I am using bluebird BTW.

Comment: instead of `return new Promise(..` at the top, `return Promise.all(...`?

Comment: @KevinB but the inner promises will still swallow errors

Comment: Why do you need the inner promises? why can't you just push the return from getBar1() to the array? I'm not too familiar with bluebird, but, if it follows the native Promise functionality, you shouldn't need `new Promise` at all in the above snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just get rid of `new Promise` all together.

```
getFoo = function() {
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(getBar1().then(function(bar1) {
        processBar1(bar1);
        return bar1;
    }));
    promises.push(getBar2().then(function(bar2) {
        processBar2(bar2);
        return bar2;
    }));
    return Promise.all(promises).spread(function(bar1, bar2) {
        var result = processBothBars(bar1, bar2);
        return result;
    });
}
```

```js
// start mock
function getBar1() {
    return Promise.resolve({name:'bar1',processed: false});
}
function getBar2() {
    return Promise.resolve({name:'bar2',processed: false});
}
function processBar1(bar1) {
  bar1.processed = true;
}
function processBar2(bar2) {
  bar2.processed = true;
}
function processBothBars (bar1, bar2) {
  return [bar1, bar2].filter(function (bar) {
    return bar.processed;
  }).map(function (bar) {
    return bar.name;
  });
}
Promise.prototype.spread = function (fn) {
  return this.then(function (arr) {
      return fn.apply(this, arr);
  });
};
// end mock

var getFoo = function (fail) {
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(getBar1().then(function (bar1) {
        processBar1(bar1);
        if (fail) {
          throw 'getBar1 Failed!';
        }
        return bar1;
    }));
    promises.push(getBar2().then(function (bar2) {
        processBar2(bar2);
        return bar2;
    }));
    return Promise.all(promises).spread(function (bar1, bar2) {
        var result = processBothBars(bar1, bar2);
        return result;
    });
}
getFoo().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); // ['bar1', 'bar2']
});
getFoo(true).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result); // doesn't happen
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.error(e); // Error: getBar1 Failed!
});
```

`.then` returns a promise, so there's no need to create a new one that wraps it unless you want to prevent errors from reaching the outer promise.

Comment: You forgot `return`ing values in the 2 `then`s

Comment: If you don't return anything, you're returning `undefined`.

Comment: Does errors from `getBar1()` get propagated to the result of `getFoo()`?

Comment: @Petah: Yes - in contrast to the code presented in the question

Comment: @Petah added demo, with (weakly) mocked .spread, only works in browsers with native Promise support. Includes error example.

Comment: (A few years later...) Don't you run the risk that all the code above the call to Promise.all could throw a synchronous exception? Isn't that a key justification for using the Promise ctor?

Comment: Ideally `getBar1` and `getBar2` would handle that problem by rejecting their own promise in the event of an error, which would essentially eliminate that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

No need to create any promises of your own here because `getBar1()` and `getBar2()` both already return promises - at least we assume so because both are thenable.

Providing `processBar1` and `processBar2` each returns the result you are interested in, the code will simplify as follows :

```
var getFoo = function() {
    // write promises as an array literal
    var promises = [
        getBar1().then(processBar1),//result returned by getBar1() is automatically passed to processBar1
        getBar2().then(processBar2) // ... ditto ...
    ];
    return Promise.all(promises).spread(processBothBars);
};
```

Comment: I don't get what that `apply` thing is doing there. Why not simplify to `.spread(processBothBars)`?

Comment: @Bergi, I wish I had thought of your `.spread(processBothBars)` thing. I confess to not being particularly spread-minded.

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw bluebird proves some sugar over this:

```
getFoo = function() {
     return Promise.join(getBar1().tap(processBar1),
                         getBar2().tap(processBar2),
                         processBothBars);
}
```

Comment: What was array doing there?

Comment: @Bergi sneaking in from the time I didn't notice a processBothBars was needed so it was a `.all`